# animation jQuery scrollTop doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery

Does animating the scrollTop property renders inaccurately. 
kindly check this code that i've made in jsbin http://jsbin.com/ewulum/2/edit

what i would like to do is when a link is clicked it would automatically scroll down to it's corresponding section. But i can't figure out what's wrong with the code on why doesn't it scroll down to the corresponding section properly. Clicking on the first two links seem to work fine.

thanks in advance.

Comment: "Clicking on the first two links seem to work fine." Yes, because there's *room* for the page to scroll. Notice the scroll bar when clicking e.g. "Link 5." It hits bottom. Possible solution: [add white space](http://jsbin.com/ewulum/3/edit).

Comment: are there any workaround instead of adding arbitrary whitespace? 

i hope there's another way to get around this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's working and animation jQuery scrollTop working properly. Just add `height:2000px` to `body` css. When you are clicking on 3rd,4th or 5th link then it scroll down and as there's no space under section 5 so scroll stop. Add some space below it or add a height on container should solve your problem.

Comment: why does adding space solve the problem?
wouldn't the browser automatically give/adjust the space for scrolling the page?

Comment: No, when you are clicking item 5 its going down to section 5 and there is no more room for scroll so it stops. Yes, you can add extra space while click on link 5 then remove/adjust that space when you don't need. You can also set overflow-y:hidden as user will not see the scroll.

Comment: thanks again. I haven't noticed of that whitespace scrolling problem.
@HADI thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine to me. The most relevant code to scroll to a particular element is:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#box').offset().top }, 2000);
```

You can add extra pixels to position it perfectly as required.

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#box').offset().top + 10 }, 2000);
```

I went into your http://jsbin.com/ewulum/2/edit and made a few changes:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:#ececec;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 250px;
}
```

JS File

```
//event delegation
$("#nav-wrapper").on("click", "a", function(e){

  var cur_el_href = $(this).attr("href"),
      cur_el_top =$(cur_el_href).offset().top;

  e.preventDefault();

  console.log("The current elem's href value is " + cur_el_href);
  console.log("The target section's offset top is " + cur_el_top);

 $(".wrapper").animate({
     scrollTop:cur_el_top
   },
   800, function(){
     //this callback is for demonstration only so as not to back to top when testing other links
         $(this).animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000);
   });

});
```

Comment: I'm wondering what's the point of setting a timer to the callback function?

btw, thanks for your response.